# non-broadcastable output operand with shape (30,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (30,30)

Tags: python

implement a new function to calculate the new objective function and gradients

Got following error
for the Stochastic Gradient descent.
I don't know what seems to be the problem
as my matrix is already 30 by 1

```
def stochastic_objective_gradient(w, xi, yi, lam):
    d = xi.shape[0]
    yx = yi * xi # 1-by-d matrix
    yxw = float(numpy.dot(yx, w)) # scalar
    
    # calculate objective function Q_i
    loss = numpy.log(1 + numpy.exp(-yxw)) # scalar
    reg = lam / 2 * numpy.sum(w * w) # scalar
    obj = loss + reg
    
    # calculate stochastic gradient
    g_loss = -yx.T / (1 + numpy.exp(yxw)) # d-by-1 matrix
    g = g_loss + lam * w # d-by-1 matrix
    
    return obj, g

def sgd(x, y, lam, stepsize, max_epoch=100, w=None):
    n, d = x.shape
    objvals = numpy.zeros(max_epoch) # store the objective values
    if w is None:
        w = numpy.zeros((d, 1)) # zero initialization
    
    for t in range(max_epoch):
        # randomly shuffle the samples
        rand_indices = numpy.random.permutation(n)
        x_rand = x[rand_indices, :]
        y_rand = y[rand_indices, :]
        
        objval = 0 # accumulate the objective values
        for i in range(n):
            xi = x_rand[i, :] # 1-by-d matrix
            yi = float(y_rand[i, :]) # scalar
            obj, g = stochastic_objective_gradient(w, xi, yi, lam)
            objval += obj
            w -= stepsize * g
        
        stepsize *= 0.9 # decrease step size
        objval /= n
        objvals[t] = objval
        print('Objective value at epoch t=' + str(t) + ' is ' + str(objval))
    
    return w, objvals
```

What can be done to match the shape?

````
    ```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-195-06f44b846812> in <module>()
          3 lam = 0
          4 stepsize = 0.1
    ----> 5 w, objvals_sgd = sgd(x_train, y_train, lam, stepsize)
    
    <ipython-input-79-54d9a7949c9d> in sgd(x, y, lam, stepsize, max_epoch, w)
         33             obj, g = stochastic_objective_gradient(w, xi, yi, lam)
         34             objval += obj
    ---> 35             w -= stepsize * g
         36 
         37         stepsize *= 0.9 # decrease step size
    
    ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (30,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (30,30)
    ```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Don't listen to the bot. This is indeed puzzling. However, I suggest providing a sample input that reproduces the error message. Please read [How to create a minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).